# Computing area with x and y coordinates, How do I break set of numbers in x and y?

Tags: java

This is what I should get.
Sample Output:

```
Please enter the coordinates in a clockwise order.
    Enter the GPS coordinates for the 1st city: 35.2270869 -80.8431267
    Enter the GPS coordinates for the 2nd city: 32.0835407 -81.0998342
    Enter the GPS coordinates for the 3rd city: 28.5383355 -81.3792365
    Enter the GPS coordinates for the 4th city: 33.7489954 -84.3879824
    The area is: 117863.342
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the coordinates in a clowise order");
        System.out.println("Enter the GPS coordinates for the 1st city: ");
        double coordinateOne= input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the GPS coordinates for the 1st city: ");
        double coordinateTwo= input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the GPS coordinates for the 1st city: ");
        double coordinateThree= input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the GPS coordinates for the 1st city: ");
        double coordinateFour= input.nextInt();

        double earthRadius= 6371.01;

        //Get distance


        //distance=(radius)arccos(sin(x1)sin(x2)+cos(x1)cos(x2)cos( y1−y2))
        double distance= (earthRadius)*Math.acos(Math.sin(coordinateOne)*Math.sin(coordinateTwo))
                + Math.cos(coordinateOne)*Math.cos(coordinateTwo);

//      System.out.println("The area is: "+distance);



    }
}
```

I am having trouble with for example if I enter `35.2270869 -80.8431267`, how do I separate them to `x` and `y`?

I must use the phrase:

```
Enter the GPS coordinates for the # city.
```

I need to separate it in order to pass them (`x` and `y`) to the formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the values you are after are `double`, `input.nextInt()` isn't going to work, instead you should be using `nextDouble`.

Now, because there are two values, you will need to read it twice...

```
double coordinateX = input.nextDouble();
double coordinateY = input.nextDouble();
```

Which, if the input was `35.2270869 -80.8431267`, would assign `35.2270869` to `coordinateX` and `-80.8431267` to `coordinateY`

You could store the values in an array for easy access...

```
double city1[] = new double[2];
city[0] = input.nextDouble();
city[1] = input.nextDouble();
```

You could even use a 2 dimensional array for storing each city...

```
double coordinates[][] = new double[4][2];
// City #1
coordinates[0][0] = input.nextDouble();
coordinates[0][1] = input.nextDouble();

// City #2
coordinates[1][0] = input.nextDouble();
coordinates[1][1] = input.nextDouble();
//...etc...
```

Oh, I should point out, you will need to add in a `input.nextLine()` after you've read the two values to remove the carriage return/newline that is in the stream from when the user pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting 35.2270869 -80.8431267 from the command line as single line, you can not get 35.2270869 -80.8431267 as integer value. Read that value as String like input.readLine(). Then split that String using split() method in String object( use '-' as the delimiter). This method is return a String array. First element of that array is having the value of 35.2270869 and then second element of that array having the 80.8431267. Then you can get those values from the String array and convert those values as double values with Double.parseDouble().

Good Luck !!!. Try and let me know

Comment: You can use space character as the delimiter of the split() method. I think SPACE character is the best one for the delimiter of the split().

Comment: It is much more simple with @MadProgrammer answer. :)

Comment: I am not yet learning to use array :/ So I am not allow to use them

Comment: According to the requirement of the question, he is trying to get get the both value from a single line and not from two line. That is why i use that approach. He is expecting "Enter the GPS coordinates for the 1st city: 35.2270869 -80.8431267" kind of approach. He had mention the expected output on the top of the codes.

Comment: @DhanushkaGayashan Yes, using `input.nextDouble` will read each value from `35.2270869 -80.8431267` `35.2270869` on the first call to `nextDouble` and `-80.8431267` on the second call to `nextDouble`, try it, it's nifty ;) - remember, there is no `nextLine` call here ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Why you are saying "here is no nextLine call here". I used that method to read input from the command line as a String.

Comment: You're assuming that we're talking about two separate inputs (by using `nextDouble`), we're not, we have a single line of input and we're extract the two double values from it, one single line of input, hence, no where did we call `nextLine` (although we should consume, but that's another issue ;))

Comment: Try it, `Scanner scanner = new Scanner("35.2270869 -80.8431267); System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble()); System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());` see what you get ;)